# dynamically add content to hubsection xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

```
XmlReader tXml = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("certain xaml code which has the desired layout..."));
UIElement MyElement = (UIElement) XamlReader.Load(tXml.ToString());
```

I need to dynamically add a `MyElement` created at runtime inside a hubsection. how can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert your xaml string between a DataTemplate tag :

```
var myXaml = "<TextBlock>test</TextBlock>";
var template = XamlReader.Load("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" + myXaml + "</DataTemplate>");
```

Don't forget to declare the default namespace and others if needed.

Next, you just have to set the ContentTemplate property of you HubSection :

```
Section1.ContentTemplate = template as DataTemplate;
```

Assuming your Hub is declared like :

```
<Hub>
    <HubSection x:Name="Section1" />
</Hub>
```